# How do you pass output from one Nextflow Channel to another and run an .Rmd file?

Tags: bash, groovy, nextflow

I have a Nextflow pipeline that has two channels.

- The first channel runs and outputs 6 `.tsv` files to a folder called 'results'.
- The second channel is supposed to use all of these 6 `.tsv` files and create a .pdf report using knitr in R in a process called 'createReport'.

My workflow code looks like this:

```
workflow {
  inputFileChannel = Channel.fromPath(params.pathOfInputFile, type: 'file') // | collect | createReport // creating channel to pass in input file
  findNumOfProteins(inputFileChannel)  // passing in the channel to the process
  findAminoAcidFrequency(inputFileChannel)
  getProteinDescriptions(inputFileChannel)
  getNumberOfLines(inputFileChannel)
  getNumberOfLinesWithoutSpaces(inputFileChannel)
  getLengthFreq(inputFileChannel)

  outputFileChannel = Channel.fromPath("$params.outdir.main/*.tsv", type: 'file').buffer(size:6)
  createReport(outputFileChannel)
```

My 'createReport' process currently looks like this:

```
process createReport {
  module 'R/4.2.2'

  publishDir params.outdir.output, mode: 'copy'


  output:
    path 'report.pdf'

  script:
      """
          R -e "rmarkdown::render('./createReport.Rmd')"
      """
}
```

And my 'createReport.Rmd' looks like this (tested in Rstudio and gives the correct .pdf output:

```
---
title: "R Markdown Practice"
author: "-"
date: "2022-12-08"
output: pdf_document
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(readr)
dataSet <- list.files(path="/Users/-/Desktop/code/nextflow_practice/results/", pattern="*.tsv")
print(dataSet)

for (data in dataSet) {
  print(paste("Showing the table for:", data))
  targetData <- read.table(file=paste("/Users/-/Desktop/code/nextflow_practice/results/", data, sep=""),
             head=TRUE,
             nrows=5,
             sep="\t") 
  print(targetData)
  
  if (data == "length_data.tsv") {
    data_to_graph <- read_tsv(paste("/Users/-/Desktop/code/nextflow_practice/results/", data, sep=""), show_col_types = FALSE)
    plot(x = data_to_graph$LENGTH,y = data_to_graph$FREQ, xlab = "x-axis", ylab = "y-axis", main = "P")
  }

  writeLines("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
}
```

What would be the correct way to write the createReport process and the workflow sections so as to be able to pass the 6 .tsv outputs from the first channel into the second channel to create the report?

Sorry I am very new to Nextflow and the documentation doesn't help me as much as I would like it to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *outputFileChannel* looks like it is trying to access files in the [publishDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir). The problem with accessing files in this directory (i.e. 'results') is that:

> Files are copied into the specified directory in an asynchronous
> manner, thus they may not be immediately available in the published
> directory at the end of the process execution. For this reason files
> published by a process must not be accessed by other downstream
> processes.

Assuming your *inputFileChannel* is intended to be a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel), you could use the following. This requires the outputs of the six process to be declared in their output blocks (using the [`path`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#output-type-path) qualifier). We could then just [mix](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#mix) and [collect](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collect) these files. Your Rmd file and list of TSV files could then be passed to your *createReport* process. Note that if you move your Rmd into the base directory of your pipeline project (i.e. in the same directory as your `main.nf` script), you can distribute it with your workflow. By providing the Rmd over a channel, this approach ensures it is staged into the process working directory when the job is run. For example:

```
workflow {

    inputFile = file( params.pathOfInputFile )

    findNumOfProteins( inputFile )
    findAminoAcidFrequency( inputFile )
    getProteinDescriptions( inputFile )
    getNumberOfLines( inputFile )
    getNumberOfLinesWithoutSpaces( inputFile )
    getLengthFreq( inputFile )

    Channel.empty() \
        | mix( findNumOfProteins.out ) \
        | mix( findAminoAcidFrequency.out ) \
        | mix( getProteinDescriptions.out ) \
        | mix( getNumberOfLines.out ) \
        | mix( getNumberOfLinesWithoutSpaces.out ) \
        | mix( getLengthFreq.out ) \
        | collect \
        | set { outputs }

    rmd = file("${baseDir}/createReport.Rmd")

    createReport( outputs, rmd )
}
```

```
process createReport {

    module 'R/4.2.2'

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/report", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path 'input_dir/*'
    path rmd

    output:
    path 'report.pdf'

    """
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('${rmd}')"
    """
}
```

Note that the *createReport* process above will stage the input TSV files under a folder called 'input_dir' in the process working directory. You could change this if you want to, but I think this keeps the working directory neat and tidy. Just be sure to modify your Rmd script to point to this folder. For example, you might choose to use something like:

```
dataSet <- list.files(path="./input_dir", pattern="*.tsv")
```

Or perhaps even:

```
dataSet <- list.files(pattern="*.tsv", recursive=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!! Ive edited my createReport process and the workflow section however it seems as though the createReport process is not running properly. I am receiving a Command exist status: 127 error.

It occurs when I get to the "Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('createReport.Rmd')" line. Perhaps I've written this command. incorrectly?

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out! I am now successfully passing the outputs from the first channel into the createReport process.

The problem now is that it successfully creates the report inside of the specific work folder that I'm copying my .Rmd file to, however I still get an error that says "missing output file(s) 'report.pdf' expected by process 'createReport'. This is weird because when I look inside the work folder, I can see the desired output. So everything runs perfectly and I get my desired output, except for that error.

Comment: @CornOnTheCob You'll get the `missing output files(s)` error if the file(s) declared in the output declaration can't be found in the process working directory (e.g. `work/9f/bdc4d3...`) when the process exits (successfully). Ensure the 'report.pdf' is written to this directory when the process exits. By default, Nextflow stages input files using symbolic links. In the answer above, the Rmd will be staged into the process working directory using a symbolic link. What directory are you copying your Rmd file to?